# How do I make a PHP variable accessible to .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to assign a variable from within PHP and make said variable available to my `.htaccess` file so that it can use the value to, for example, deny or allow access.

Example `index.php` file:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['REMOTE_USER'] = 'valid';
  $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] = 'valid';
  $_ENV['REMOTE_USER'] = 'valid';
  putenv('REMOTE_USER=valid');
  print 'You are allowed.';
```

Here is one example of what I've tried inside the `.htaccess` file (which is in the same directory as `index.php`):

```
# Doesn't work... Always denied.
SetEnvIf Remote_User valid allowed
SetEnvIf Remote_User notvalid disallowed
Deny from all
Allow from env=allowed
```

Is there a way to allow or deny access through `.htaccess` based on values provided by PHP?

Comment: The only remotely feasible option (if you really need that approach) is to create temporary state/lock files in conjunction to just setting a PHP session variable. Their existence could then be probed by extracting the ID from `%{HTTP_COOKIE}` and a simple RewriteCond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers already state, you are having a chicken/egg problem: the fact that the PHP is running means the `.htaccess` saw no reason to forbid it, and its work is done.

Denying access to a page in PHP, where you should be doing more complex authentication and authorization stuff, is trivial though:

```
if($myUser->shouldNotBeHere()) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
  die('Access denied!');
}
```

This looks the same as an Apache-level `deny` to the browser.

Answer (score 4):

The `.htaccess` file is run *before* the PHP script is run. In other words, what you are describing is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

`.htaccess` is read by the server *before* PHP file, so what you seek is quite impossible.

On the other hand, you may set PHP variables inside `.htaccess`

```
SetEnv HTTP_MY_VARIABLE "my value"
```

Maybe *that* would help you somehow